# cron every X exact meaning

Tags: cron

In cron you can specify */n where n means every n times period, for instance in the first column is minute.

```
*/5 means every 5 minutes, but which minutes? 0, 5, 10, ...?
```

What happens if the number specified is not a divisor of 60?

```
*/7 what will happen, will it start to skew in the next hour?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It'll go on 7, 14, ... 56, 0, 7, 14, ...

With that syntax, I like to think of it as going when `t mod x === 0`

Answer (score 6):

In crontab, `*` is a shorthand for `first-last` (where `first` is the minimum possible value and `last` is the maximum possible value).

The syntax `first-last/step` means "every `N` where `N >= first` and `N <= last` and `(N - first) % step == 0`".

So `*/7` in minutes means the same as `0,7,14,21,28,35,42,49,56`.  But `1-59/7` means `1,8,15,22,29,36,43,50,57`.

Comment: So I'm not sure if I understand, Why did you choose 1 for first and not 0?

Comment: @stivlo, to illustrate the difference between `0-59/7` (a.k.a. `*/7`) and `1-59/7`.